# Passing std::function as a parameter

Tags: c++, std-function

I am trying to pass a std::function as a parameter.  I am having a couple of problems with the syntax.

The code is simple.  I want to save a function handler into a `std::map`.  I don't want to make the `registerHandler` method a template.   Here is the code example.

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class message
{ 
  public:
      void print(string command)
      {
         cout << "message id: " << id_ << "  content: " << command << std::endl;
      }
      int id_ = 0;
};

std::map<int, function<void(string)>> functionMap;

void registerHandler(int id, message& messageClass, std::function<void(string)>& func)
{
  auto messageHandler = bind(&func, &messageClass, placeholders::_1);

  // ERROR #2
  // functionMap.insert({id, messageHandler});
}

int main()
{
  message msg1;
  msg1.id_ = 5000;

  // ERROR #1
  // registerHandler(msg1.id_, msg1, message::print);

  std::map<int, function<void(string)>>::iterator iter;
  iter = functionMap.begin();
  while (iter != functionMap.end())
  {
     int key = iter->first;
     auto messageHandler = iter->second;
     messageHandler("Junk Payload");

     iter++;
  }
}
```

ERROR#1

```
message.cc:37:44: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘void message::print(std::string)’
   registerHandler(msg1.id_, msg1, message::print);
```

ERROR#2

```
message.cc: In function ‘void registerHandler(int, message&, std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>)>&)’:
message.cc:24:42: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<int, std::function<void(std::basic_string<char>)> >::insert(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   functionMap.insert({id, messageHandler});
                                          ^
```

Comment: Please post an answer with the solution that you figured out, so that the next person with the same problem will know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your program like this to work:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class message
{
public:
   void print(string command)
   {
      cout << "message id: " << id_ << "  content: " << command << std::endl;
   }
   int id_ = 0;
};

std::map<int, function<void(string)>> functionMap;

void registerHandler(int id, message& messageClass, const std::function<void(string)>& func)
{
   functionMap.insert({id, func});
}

int main()
{
   message msg1;
   msg1.id_ = 5000;

   registerHandler(msg1.id_, msg1, bind(&message::print, &msg1, placeholders::_1));

   std::map<int, function<void(string)>>::iterator iter;
   iter = functionMap.begin();
   while (iter != functionMap.end())
   {
      int key = iter->first;
      auto messageHandler = iter->second;
      messageHandler("Junk Payload");

      iter++;
   }
}
```